# 0x0000007F Stop error on a Windows-based computer , blue screen appears unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

[image: Here are the details about my Computer shutdown]
Hello everyone, two years ago this website helped me to solve a big problem.
 This time I have a problem of 0x0000007F Stop error (picture attached) on a Windows-based computer in the middle of my work few times a week. 
How can I make it stop happening?

Comment: What's your question to us exactly? What has your research shown you so far?  What have you attempted already, and what were the results?

Comment: Hi Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, my question is: how to stop that  ?

Comment: I downloaded the hotfix "Fix472467" from Microsoft website, after that it unzipped itself , till now everything is fine . Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a fix for this here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2885978

> This issue is caused by stack exhaustion that occurs when the computer
>   sends and receives Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) or Server
>   Message Block (SMB) data. Stack exhaustion occurs because the thread
>   on which the TCP and SMB data is received and sent does not have
>   sufficient stack space to complete the call.

Comment: Does the fix explain what has happened or how to fix it manually?  It would be good to provide as much detail as possible here in case the link changes or goes dead.

Comment: Thank you David King, I downloaded the hotfix "Fix472467", after that it unzipped itself . Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: I've not actually gone through the install myself so I don't know what the full process is.  I do know you'll need to reboot after applying the patch to make the changes take effect.